# When do equality and inequality constrained problems agree?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$ and $h:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$. Consider a solution $x^\ast$ to the equality constrained optimisation problem
$$ x^\ast \in \underset{x}{\text{argmin}} f(x)  \quad\text{subject to} \quad h(x) = 0,$$
supposing at least one exists. What are sufficient conditions that guarantee that $x^\ast$ is also a solution to the corresponding inequality constrained problem, so that
$$ f(x^\ast) = \underset{y}{\text{min}} f(y) \quad\text{subject to} \quad h(y) \leq 0?$$